# Strange artifacts in 3D programs on Mac

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, mac, 3d, visual-artifacts

I recently upgraded from 10.04 to 12.04 on my MacBook 7,1. Now, in any 3D program, strange rectangular artifacts cover some of the screen; they seem to be dependent on displayed objects. This is, of course, having the effect of ****gasp in horror**** rendering my games unplayable. Before I asphyxiate due to lack of 3D games, or choke on a rectangle, how can I fix this?

I am running Metacity on GNOME Fallback on Ubuntu 12.04.

```
$ sudo lshw -C video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:92000000-92ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff memory:90000000-91ffffff ioport:1000(size=128) memory:93000000-9301ffff
```

Video card: NVIDIA Corporation Device 08a0 (rev a2)

Nothing appears under additional drivers, and I would prefer to avoid proprietary software.

Wings 3d:
[image: Illustration of artifacts]

Neverputt:
[image]

Comment: @EliahKagan I added the information you requested. Also, thanks for the user-friendly instructions, but I'm okay without this level of detail :D

Comment: Those two lines are the *only* output of `sudo lshw -C video`?

Comment: @EliahKagan Actually, now that I look again I can see many lines overwriting each other, but I find no way to see them individually.

Comment: @EliahKagan The graphics problem never happens in anything which isn't 2D, and is almost certainly not the cause of the overwrite, as this behavior is unique to this specific command. In addition, `Video card: ...` is not part of the output, and the formatting made that clear until you changed it.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for changing it back. Can we [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7516/discussion-between-eliah-kagan-and-arafinwe)? (For long back-and-forth communication, that tends to work better than comments.)

Answer (score 2):

This could be due to running the Nouveau drivers rather than the proprietary Nvidia drivers. Have you verified if you are running on the proprietary drivers?

Comment: I am not running any proprietary drivers.

Comment: That could be the reason then. I've also had some problems with Nouveau in the past. 2 questions then: were you running Nouveau drivers in 10.04? And are the graphical errors fixed by switching to the proprietary drivers?

Comment: I found this: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/macbook-pro-7-1-nvidia-drivers-64-bit-912720/ which may bring about some explanations.